# Trying to prove logarithms preserve limits without any notion of continuity

Tags: analysis, limits

I am trying to prove that if ${s_n}$ is a convergent sequence, $\lim_{ n \to \infty} s_n = s$ iff  $\lim_{ n \to \infty} \log(s_n) = \log(s)$.  I don't have any notion of continuity yet (although I know that continuous functions are precisely the ones that preserve limits),  so i am trying to do this without that fact.  This is part of a larger problem where i have a sequence $s_n$ which i am trying to show converges to 1, but so far i managed to show $log(s_n)$ converges to $0$.

Comment: The fact that the logarithm function is monotone should come in very handy. So should the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x^{1/n}=1$ whenever $x>0$, I think.

Comment: Well, what definition of $\log$ are you using?

Comment: Mike: Maybe by looking at how you got to log(s_n) --> 0 you can "work backwards" and see how to actually get s_n --> 1 on reversing the steps.